# Simple console app cannot load fle or assembly `DocumentFormat.OpenXml`

Tags: c#, xml, openxml

I have a console app with the following contents in the project file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <PlatformTarget>AnyCPU</PlatformTarget>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
    <RootNamespace>basic_example</RootNamespace>
    <ImplicitUsings>disable</ImplicitUsings>
    <StartupObject>basic_example.SpreadSheetWriterExample</StartupObject>
  </PropertyGroup>
    
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="DocumentFormat.OpenXml" Version="2.14.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And the following in `SpreadsheetWriterExample.cs`:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml;
using DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Spreadsheet;
using System.Text;

namespace basic_example
{
   class SpreadSheetWriterExample
   {

      public static void CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(string filepath)
      {
         // Create a spreadsheet document by supplying the filepath.
         // By default, AutoSave = true, Editable = true, and Type = xlsx.
         Console.WriteLine("creating spreadsheet document");
         try
         {
            using (SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(filepath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
               spreadsheetDocument.Close();
            }
         }
         catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("DirectoryNotFoundException");
         }
         catch (IOException e)
         {
            Console.WriteLine("IOException");
         }
      }

      static void Main(string[] args)
      {
         
         CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook("test.xlsx");
      }
   }
}
```

When I try to run the solution I get the following error:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.14.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fb06cb64d019a17' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> at basic_example.SpreadSheetWriterExample.CreateSpreadsheetWorkbook(String filepath)
>
> at basic_example.SpreadSheetWriterExample.Main(String[] args) in SpreadSheetWriterExample.cs:line 39

I don't really know what is going wrong since I have explicitly set the reference to `OpenXml` in the project file. Furthermore I can't really follow the stack since the exception just tells me that it's coming from somewhere inside the `CreateSpreadSheetWorkbook` method.

What is causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've reproduced this issue. I managed to fix it by adding the following to the main project `PropertyGroup`:

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Note that if your project targets .NET5.0 or .NET6.0, this is not necessary.

There seems to be [an open issue for this on Nuget's GitHub](https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4837).

Here's [the documentation for `CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#copylocallockfileassemblies).

Comment: I'm intentionally targetting `netstandard2.0` for other reasons. Any further comments or background on why this fixes the problem?

Comment: @user32882 Seems to be some kind of bug, at least that's what I got from reading the issue on GitHub that I linked.

Comment: sorry for the follow up question, but it would be very educational for me to figure out how you ended up in the page for that bug. I don't see the stack trace for my error anywhere in that thread and yet somehow you used it to solve the problem...

Comment: @user32882 I searched for `nuget dependency not copied` which took me to https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e6cc73f3-050c-4a0a-b9e5-42bf904a163f/nuget-package-manager-does-not-copy-depenencies-to-output?forum=csharpgeneral